# How can I make Angular model work in html page?

Tags: html, angular, components

I connect with my service without any problem, then I import it into a model, but when I try to print the data with a for loop in the html page, it comes up blank. Where do you think I am doing wrong?

this is component file

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ResultsModel } from 'src/app/core/models/results.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-results',
  templateUrl: './results.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./results.component.scss']
})


export class ResultsComponent implements OnInit {
    
    clientResults : ResultsModel[] = [];


    constructor(private httpRequestService : HttpRequestService) {}



    ngOnInit(): void {
        
        this.getAllResults();
        
    }


    getAllResults(){
        let apiEndpoint = "results"
        this.httpRequestService.getApi(apiEndpoint, false).subscribe(resultRequest => {
          this.clientResults = resultRequest
          return this.clientResults
         
          
    })
}
```

this is model file

```
export interface ResultsModel {
    "result": string,
    "createddate": string,
    "clientid": string,
    "id": number,
    "clientusername": string,
    
}
```

this is html file

```
<table class="table align-middle table-nowrap" id="invoiceTable">
    <thead class="text-muted">
        <tr>
            
            <th class="sort text-uppercase" data-sort="invoice_id">User Id</th>
            <th class="sort text-uppercase" data-sort="customer_name">Username</th>
            <th class="sort text-uppercase" data-sort="email">Type</th>
            
            <th class="sort text-uppercase" data-sort="date">Type</th>
            <th class="sort text-uppercase" data-sort="invoice_amount">Type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let results in clientResults">
        
        <td>{{results.id}}</td>
        <td class="customer_name">{{results.username}}</td>
        <td>{{results.clientid}}</td>
        <td>{{results.result}}</td>
        <td>{{results.createddate}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Where do you think I went wrong? Where could I be doing wrong?

Comment: If this is really your code as is, then it is caused by a typo. Remove the closing bracket after `clientResults : ResultsModel[] = [];`

Comment: I tried as I edited above, I did what you said, but the result is the same.

Comment: @E.Maggini do you have an idea?

Comment: Can you provide the JSON response received? Did you check the DevTools prompt any error?

Comment: Your `results.username` should be `results.clientusername`. Also, any errors or warnings from the DevTools console?

Comment: @imuzz01add the following somewhere in your html outside the table: `{{ clientResults | json }}` to see what's in there. Share the screen and your dev tools console.